# Is there a 32 bit version of Windows 8 OS available?

Tags: windows-8, 32-bit

I am searching for a Windows 8 32 bit OS for my Lenovo G580 laptop, I heard that Microsoft only provides 64 bit OS for customers.

Is there any way to use a 32 bit windows 8 OS on my laptop?

Comment: Well ofc there is a 32bit you can just use Google "Windows 8 32-bit" to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes, there is a 32-bit version of Windows 8, just simply search it you will get enough [evidence](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Windows+8+32-Bit&go=&qs=ds&form=QBRE).
The easiest way to get one is buying one DVD and install it directly.